# Get Camera Folder path of all android Phones

Tags: android, camera

I was wondering how can you get the camera Folder path of any android phone without the user taking a picture

```
String cameraPath =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();
```

This is what I'm currently using it doesn't get the path for all phones

Comment: There is no requirement for a camera app to store images at any particular location, let alone one that you can access. `DIRECTORY_DCIM` is the recommended root for photos taken by typical camera apps. However, a camera app can do what it wants, including not storing the image as a file at all (e.g., directly uploading it to a server).

Comment: thank you  this will help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Let me makes things clear. It is not possible to get camera folder of any android device. Why? Because there is no standard for storing medias. Some devices use camera folder, some DCMI folder, even some devices change ther folder when the storage get full.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but as it keeps poping up in my searches I'll leave some updated info on the topic maybe someone will find it useful.

1. From my experience and docs, as others pointed out from the beginning, there is no "Universal" way of getting file paths on all possible devices.
2. Along with the Android 11 rollout Scoped Storage will be introduced and it will affect how developers interact with the device storage. I'll leave some details below:

   - Google Video from Dev summit 2019 ([Preparing for Scoped Storage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnJ3amzJM94))
   - Google docs [Storage Overview](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)
   - Android 11 Storage Updates [docs](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage)
   - And the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) for handling Media Storage

On the same topic, for a long time in my app I used an approach very similar to the answer below, from Savsani, and it worked very well. Unfortunately this is no longer ok in my case starting OS 10, so I had to adapt my code with changes mentioned in last link (*...official docs for Handling Media storage*)

Hope it helps someone.

P.S. I had some serious compatibility issues using the recommended ContentUri

```
int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
int nameColumn =
        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
int durationColumn =
        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);
int sizeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE);

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // Get values of columns for a given video.
    long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
    String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
    int duration = cursor.getInt(durationColumn);
    int size = cursor.getInt(sizeColumn);

    Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
```

The issue was related to getting the path from Gallery folder on device that came in the form: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A74`

What seems to work best in this scenario is to keep both path parsing methods in code and differentiate accordingly. At least for now, as I have to release an update. Once I'll find a more elegant solution, if I see anybody is still interested in this topic I'll post it here.

Update:

After multiple tests and approaches I decided that the best way to go to in order to include as many devices as possible is to check if the the file uploaded is a media file (more options in Savsani's answer)and get the file path directly from that URI with no manipulation

```
 public static String filePathFrom(Uri uri) {
        if (uri == null) return null;

        ContentResolver resolver = Fbn.getInstance().getContentResolver();
        FileInputStream input = null;
        FileOutputStream output = null;


        try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = resolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            if (pfd == null) {
                return null;
            }
            FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
            input = new FileInputStream(fd);

            File outputDir = context.getCacheDir();
            File outputFile = File.createTempFile("photo_", ".jpg", outputDir);
            String tempFilename = outputFile.getAbsolutePath();
            output = new FileOutputStream(tempFilename);

            int read;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
            while ((read = input.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                output.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

            return new File(tempFilename).getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {

            ignored.getStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (input != null) {
                    input.close();
                }
                if (output != null) {
                    output.close();
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: I managed to properly parse images coming from the Gallery folder by directly obtaining the path from the URI without any further manipulating the selected uri string. Updated original answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use this method for get path of media.

This will ***work*** in ***all android devices***.

Just pass context and Uri for get path of media.

**Example :**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// Your other code goes here for get Image from camera or gallery
        Uri fileUri = data.getData();
        String path = getPath(getApplicationContext(), fileUri); 
}
```

This method will give you a path of file in any android device.

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            The context.
     * @param uri
     *            The Uri to query.
     * @param selection
     *            (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs
     *            (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = { column };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     *            The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     *            The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     *            The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
```